# How to Sync Child Databases based on record type?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, service-broker

We have a situation where it is an unmovable requirement to have two separate databases, but we want to keep the single web-based front end that we currently use to manipulate what used to be a single database. Records need to go in a child database based on the value of a column, let's say employee type "hourly" vs. "salaried".

There are a lot of synonyms, stored procedures, and other bits of SQL that lie between the web interface and the database, so we figured that instead of doing the split there we could use the current database as a "master" database and then have something *behind it* direct the data into either of the two child databases. (as in the following diagram:)

[image: Database diagram]

We seem to be good to the extent that data flows one way (from the web interface to the child databases) - to the extent that data flows back the other way (from the child databases to the master), we seem to get into some hairy situations.

Some of them seem intractable (e.g. if one person on child DB A inserts a record with an autoincrement ID of 1 at the same time a person on child DB B inserts a record with the same Id of 1), but most of them seem to just be a pain in the ass.

My question is: **Does there exist a solution that will allow us to sync these databases, but allow us to insert the logic of "only if the employee column has a status of X", rather than just blindly mirroring them?**

Here are a few ideas that were floated around: triggers seem to have potential but seem to be a lot of work as well, and we were wondering if there were any tools out there that could do the heavy lifting of the sync for us. Does anyone out there have any ideas?

- triggers
- Service Broker
- SSIS
- Microsoft Sync Framework

Comment: Is the idea that the child databases will never be directly written to or read from the web app?  The web app will only interface with the parent database?

Comment: Yes - this way the web app will not have to change at all, and the master DB will have to change only minimally if at all (e.g. to add triggers)

Comment: Why not [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

So this is really more of an opinion thing, because there are possibilities with each solution that you already identified.  There is no easy solution, but a lightweight approach would be to use CDC in combination with SSIS.  SSIS has built in hooks to work with CDC and CDC will provide better performance with your master database -  it will not involve the kind of waits that could occur from using triggers that insert data into another database.

[Here is more on CDC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)